# Why is this question of mine being downvoted?

Tags: support, specific-question, downvotes

I have asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618057/execute-a-jar-file-in-a-specific-jre). I got downvoted because the user didn't like what I had to ask. I feel very much discouraged from asking questions on here, and the question I had was not low quality, or off-topic.

I don't think it's fair that I have been following the guidelines and I have been making references in my question and using your correct convention, and I still get downvoted. Furthermore, I am novice in some areas of programming and OS environments, and it seems like when I ask a question I am getting downvoted for it being a "stupid question". Can anyone justify why this question would be downvoted?

Comment: You received one downvote by a random user, while four people contributed answers that helped you. That outcome shouldn't be discouraging.

Comment: It does when Stackoverflow restricts users from asking questions based on down-votes.

Comment: Voting is anonymous, nobody can justify the vote of an unknown user.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't restrict users based on a single downvote. Or even two.

Comment: -1 on that first revision is about where it should have been. You forgot to show the error that exposed the problem. I would have reverted afterwards if I was the downvoter, but you can't count on people to come back (the one thing I think is most broken about the voting system).

Comment: Hmm, no, that isn't broken.  Editing the question re-activates it and pushes it back on the front page.  I tend to take a quick look, not always.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I assume that the downvote came before your first revision. That version of the question didn't show much research effort, it just posed the problem. Maybe the voter will reconsider the downvote after seeing your revisions, but if not, relax, move on. Voting behavior (both ways) can be incomprehensible anyway.

Maybe a lesson for next time: show what you tried right from the start. That's usually appreciated.